# How to bootstrap UI5 resources without CDN in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, sapui5

I'm doing a walkthrough for SAPUI5.

The code `src="/resources/sap-ui-core.js"` doesn't work, because I can't find this directory in my project.

When using a CDN URL, it works fine. But I don't want to use CDN for my application.

So how can I get and import the `sap-ui-core.js` file into my project so that it is saved on my computer locally?

I'm working with Eclipse btw. and installed the *SAPUI5 Tools for Eclipse*.

Comment: SAP abandoned the SAPUI5 plugin for Eclipse. Please read https://blogs.sap.com/2019/11/26/sapui5-tools-for-eclipse-now-is-the-time-to-look-for-alternatives/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SAPUI5-Plugin for eclipse includes the SAPUI5 library files.

If you start the App using "Run as..."->"Web App Preview" on your index.html, eclipse starts a jetty http server which serves the SAPUI5 library at `/resources`.

As long as you don't close the preview window in eclipse you can use any browser to debug your application at the url you find in that preview window.

Comment: Checkout the SAPUI5 Plugin and more sap development tools on this [link](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#sapui5)

Answer (score -1):

Check that the dependencies are correct in your project, because the general dependency file such as sap.m may be missing in the project file.

Comment: As the question author had described, bootstrapping with a CDN URL works. This issue is therefore not related to control libs being missing.